# Find highest total price by selling items to multiple buyers, limited by user input to how many separate sales can be made

Tags: php, algorithm, combinations, mathematical-optimization

EDIT: Im sorry guys my explantion of the problem wasn't clear! This should be better:

1. User sends ID numbers of articles and the max. number of bundles(packages)
2. API searches for all prices available for the articles and calculates best result for min. number of bundles (limit to max. number provided by customer)
   ONE Bundle is one package of items delivered to ONE platform(buyer)

Thanks!

Comment: There seems to be a missing constraint, such as that buyers can bid for multiple items at some price, but must be guaranteed to get the quantity asked for. Otherwise this is "distribute items for highest sales price", and that's wholly uncomplicated.

Comment: Between your question title and your description of the problem, it's not clear whether the seller has a limited number of sales (transactions) or a limited number of buyers he/she may sell to.

Comment: @mark-elliot you may find it uncomplicated but I don't have a clue where to start, It would be hepful to me if you could give me some idea of where to start, telling me "that's easy" and not giving any adivice isnt really all that helpful.

Comment: @chris, he has a limited number of buyers he may sell to. Think of it that he has X number of boxes to put items in (any number of items will fit in each box) so one box per buyer can be sent, up to the total number of boxes the user has available

Comment: Are the items all identical or all different? In other words, does the seller have, say, 10 units of a single item (and each buyer is offering a single per unit price and a maximum number of units to buy) or 1 unit of 10 different items (and each buyer is offering a different price for the one unit of each item)?

Comment: Updated my question to be (hopefully) clearer. I'm sorry about the terrible wording of the original question I guess I should never go into technical writing! @mhum the user has all different items to sell (although he COULD have more than one of each, but we don't care)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fun little problem. I spent a few hours on it this morning, and while I don't have a complete solution, I think I have enough for you to get started (which I believe was what you asked for).

First of all, I'm assuming these things, based on your description of the problem:

- All buyers quote a price for all the items
- There's no assumption about the items, they may all be different
- The user can only interact with a limited number of buyers
- The user wants to sell every item, each to one buyer
- The user may sell multiple items to a single buyer

**Exact solution -- brute force approach**

For this, the first thing to realize is that, for a given set of buyers, it is straight forward to calculate the maximum total revenue, because you can just choose the highest price offered in that set of buyers for each item. Add up all those highest prices, and you have the max total revenue for that set of buyers.

Now all you have to do is make that calculation for every possible combination of buyers. That's a basic combinations problem: "n choose k" where n is the total number of buyers and k is the number of buyers you're limited to. There are functions out there that will generate lists of these combinations (I wrote my own... there's also [this PEAR package](http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Combinatorics) for php).

Once you have a max total revenue for every combination of chosen buyers, just pick the biggest one, and you've solved the problem.

**More elegant algorithm?**

However, as I intimated by calling this "brute force", the above is not fast, and scales horribly. My machine runs out of memory with 20 buyers and 20 items. I'm sure a better algorithm exists, and I've got a good one, but it isn't perfect.

It's based on opportunity costs. I calculate the difference between the highest price and the second highest price for each item. That difference is an opportunity cost for not picking the buyer with that highest price.

Then I pick buyers offering high prices for items where the opportunity cost is the highest (thus avoiding the worst opportunity costs), until I have k - 1 buyers (where k is the max I can pick). The final choice is tricky, and instead of writing a much more complicated algorithm, I just run all the possibilities for the final buyer and pick the best revenue.

This strategy picks the best combination most of the time, and if it misses, it doesn't miss much. Its also scales relatively well. It's 10x faster than brute force on small scales, and if I quadruple all the parameters (buyers, buyer limit, and items), calculation time goes up by a factor of 20. Considering how many combinations are involved, that's pretty good.

I've got some code drafted, but it's too long for this post. Let me know if you're interested, and I'll figure out a way to send it to you.

Comment: Thank you! Thats some great information and you've clearly gone out of your way to investigate it, id love to see the code if you would send it to me :) not sure if we can send private messages on here or anything?

Comment: My email is on my profile. I'd also accept one of those nice green checkmarks by my response if you think it answered your question ;-)

Comment: Hey chris, still not been able to find your email adress on your profile. Would you be able to email me on promanex a}t gm#a-il dot com please? would love to see the code you wrote for this problem

Answer (score 1):

This is a graph problem. It can be solved with the Edmond's Blossom V algorithm. It's a matching algorithm to find the best pairwise matching for example in dating programs. Maybe you want to look for the 1d bin-packing algorithm. In 1d bin-packing you have a limit items to assign to unlimited boxes or shelves the better the boxes get filled.

Comment: This does not seem applicable. There is a single seller and multiple buyers.

Comment: I've corrected my answer but the question is a bit hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, it is NP-complete via reduction from [Minimum Set Cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem). We can translate an instance of Set Cover into an instance of the OP's problem as follows:

Let an instance of Set Cover be given by a set *X* of size *n* and a collection of subsets *S_1*, *S_2*, ..., *S_m* of *X*. Construct an instance of the OP's problem where the seller has *n* items to sell to *m* buyers, where buyer *i* offers a price of 1 for item *j* if *S_i* contains item *j* and 0 otherwise. A solution to the OP's problem where the number of buyers is limited by *k* and the total price paid is *n* corresponds to a solution to the original Set Cover problem with *k* sets. So, if you had a polynomial-time solution to the OP's problem, you could solve Minimum Set Cover by successively solving it for the case of 1, 2, 3, etc... buyers until you found a solution with total price equal to *n*.